# vue.js: create component from string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, backend, vuejs3

I have two components named component-1 and component-2, along with this vue.js code:

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <input class="input" @keyup="update()">
      <div class="render"></div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   methods:{
      update () {
         document.querySelector(".render").innerHTML=`<component-${
            document.querySelector(".input").value
         } />`
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Whenever I run the code, the component doesn't render. Is there a way to get this component to render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the right way to render components dynamically in `Vue` - instead you should use [`:is`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <input class="input" @keyup="update($event.target.value)">
      <component :is="myComponent"></component>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
     return {
       myComponent: undefined
     }
   },
   methods:{
      update (component) {
         this.myComponent = component
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

A sandbox demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vuex-4-test-forked-gx67s?file=/src/App.vue)